# How to record video using ffmpeg on android?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, android-camera, record

I want to create a video using ffmpeg by taking byte[] data from Android Camera. Now the problem is i don't have much knowledge about ffmpeg. So i need some documentation on ffmpeg. I will appreciate if anyone can provide some useful tutorial / sample code / example on ffmpeg and how it works , how it can be used to create video programmatically, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ffmpeg is a C library so you will have to use NDK to build it and bridge it together with your Android device using a JNI interface. As far as I know, I dont think its possible to record a video directly using ffmpeg. However, you can use openCv to capture video stream then decode/encode it with ffmpeg if you decided to go this route. Once again, all of this must be done in C/C++, and the information can be sent to the android device via JNI using NDK once you finished processing it with ffmpeg.

Here is the link to OpenCV Library for Android
http://opencv.org/downloads.html

Once downloaded, there are sample projects which show you how to record video using native android camera and as well as using opencv feature.

Comment: I am using openCV too. But the thing is i have to process the camera preview & show them and also have to capture them at a time. I dont know how to do that exactly. I haven't find any example on that. So if it possible for you to help me with that ? Do you have any idea/hints on how to do that?

Comment: You can be interested in this sample: http://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/samples/RecordActivity.java